# Passing image from server to adapter without saving in drawable

Tags: java, android, android-volley, picasso

I am working with a adapter/cardLayout/recycleView and i used [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465) tutorial to set that up

everything works fine, now i need to download a image(i use picasso) and set that up in the cardlayout, the thing is i need to pass it on each **card** :/

**Here is what i do at the moment:**

```
public class SimiliarPhotos extends AppCompatActivity implements IResult {

    RecyclerView rv;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    ArrayList<Plant> plants = new ArrayList<Plant>();
    SimiliarPlantsAdapter adapter;

    VolleyService mVolleyService;
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    final String GETREQUEST = "GETCALL";

    //login url connection
    final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/plants";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_similiar_photos);

        rv = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);


        initializeAdapter();

        initVolleyCallback();

        mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);

        mVolleyService.getDataVolley(GETREQUEST,URL);
    }


    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
        Log.d("resposta",response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
        Log.d("resposta",response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("resposta",error.toString());
    }

    void initVolleyCallback(){
        mResultCallback = new IResult() {
            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
            }

            @Override
            public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONArray response) {
                Plant plant;
                Log.d("ENTERED","ENTEREDHERE1");
                // iterate over the JSONArray response
                for (int i=0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i); // get the individual object from JSONArray
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(object.getString("id")); // get the unique identifier from the object
                        String specie = object.getString("specie"); // get the name of the specie from the object
                        String description = object.getString("description"); // get the description of the object
                        ImageLoad(specie);
                        plant = new Plant(id,specie,description); // construct the object
                        Log.d("plant",String.valueOf(plant));
                        plants.add(plant); // add the object to the arraylist so it can be used on the cardLayout

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d("ENTERED",e.toString());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("resposta",error.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    public void ImageLoad(String specie){
        String urlFoto = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/images/" + specie + "/Thumbnail.jpg";
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(urlFoto)
                .into(imageView);

    }

    public void initializeAdapter(){
        Log.d("plants",String.valueOf(plants.size()));
        adapter = new SimiliarPlantsAdapter(plants);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

how can i pass that image into the correct card? any tip?

Comment: do it in your `SimiliarPlantsAdapter` BindViewholder method.

Comment: @Filipe Image should have set in `onBindHolder` adapter not in activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to load images by `Picasso` in `onBindViewHolder` method of Adapter . See what I am doing in my adapter..

```
public class OffersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OffersAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<OffersModel> list;
    Context mContext;


    public OffersAdapter(Context mContext, List<OffersModel> list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_offers, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OffersModel offersModel = list.get(position);
        holder.product.setText(offersModel.getProduct());
        holder.description.setText(offersModel.getDiscription());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(offersModel.getImageurl())
            .into(holder.offersimage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView offersimage;
        TextView product,description,category;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            offersimage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offersimage);
            product = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offertitle);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerdescription);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your `ImageLoad (String Species) { . . }` method call as well as implementation. Create your adapter class like this.

```
public class SimplePlants extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimplePlants.MyViewHolder> {
private List<Plant> list;
Context mContext;


public SimplePlants(Context mContext, List<Plant> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_single_plant_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Plant plant = list.get(position);
    holder.species.setText(plant.getSpecies ());
    holder.description.setText(plant.getDiscription());

    loadImage (holder.image, plant.getSpecies ());
}

public void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String specie){
    String urlFoto = "http://10.0.2.2:3000/images/" + specie + "/Thumbnail.jpg";
    Picasso.with(this)
            .load(urlFoto)
            .into(imageView);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView species,description;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        species = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}
}
```

I hope this will help you.